# Loading Files from Directory

Tags: php, file

i have this code that loads files from a certain directory, i am trying to limit the number of files to 50. Right now if the its loading all the files. Can someone have a look at this code and tell me how to set a limit to number of files

```
    function dirList ($directory) 
{
    $results = array();
    $handler = opendir($directory);
    while ($file = readdir($handler)) 
    {
        if ($file != '.' && $file != '..')
        {
            $pos = strrpos($file,".");
            $ph = strtolower(substr($file,$pos+1,strlen($file)-$pos));
            if($ph == "jpg" || $ph == "jpeg" || $ph == "gif" || $ph == "png" || $ph == "bmp")
            {
                $results[] = $file;
            }
        }
    }
    closedir($handler);
    return $results;
}
```

Comment: `while ($file = readdir($handler) && count($results) < 50 )`

Comment: Thanks for your quick response but that didn't work. Now it wouldn't load any files at all.

Comment: In the hard brackets for your array you could us $i as a variable for incriments and limit your increments to 50

Answer (score 0):

In the hard brackets for your array you could us $i as a variable for increments and limit your increments to 50

```
for($i=0; $i<50; $i++){
$results[$i] = $file;
}
```

ADDITION:

```
<?php

for($i=0; $i<10; $i++){
echo $i;
}
```

?>

should return 0123456789

Comment: Hard bracket?? can you show me what you mean? i am trying to set a limit of 50 files from that directory.  Thanks

Comment: Thanks, but now it would load the same image. It fixed the limit to 50 but its displaying the same image file 50 times.

Comment: What happens with echo $i; inside of the { bracket } just after the for() loop?

Comment: I didn't get your question, when i added that code, its suppose to load 50 images from that directory but now its loading 50 images but its the same image 50 times.

Comment: i will add more info my answer. what do you get when you echo $i ?

Comment: when i echo $i it loads the files from the directory  but its loading the same file.

Comment: Echoing $i by itself should only return numbers. My guess is that 1. It is only returning a single number bc the increment is not working the way it should or 2. We should be returning $results inside of the curly braces. But I am trying to figure out exactly the issue is right now

Comment: make sure that you are returning your $results within the curly braces of the for loop

Answer (score 0):

You should add a count variable and break the look on reaching 50.

**Edited Below**

I am modifying your function and I have tested and it is working fine.

```
function dirList ($directory) {
$results = array();
$handler = opendir($directory);
$count = 0;
while ($file = readdir($handler)) 
{
    if($count == 50) break;
    if ($file != '.' && $file != '..')
    {
        $pos = strrpos($file,".");
        $ph = strtolower(substr($file,$pos+1,strlen($file)-$pos));
        if($ph == "jpg" || $ph == "jpeg" || $ph == "gif" || $ph == "png" || $ph == "php")
        {
            $count++;
            $results[] = $file;
        }
    }
}
closedir($handler);
return $results; }
```

Comment: there must be some mistake... let me edit my answer and add the modified function